# Postgres convert Varchar [] to JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, migration

I am trying to create migration and change column type from varchar[] to JSON. What I would like to achieve to have JSONs in the following format

```
["US", "UK", "GER"] -> { "US": [], "UK": [], "GER": []}
```

Existing Table :

```
CREATE TABLE countries (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, destinations VARCHAR [] NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO countries(destinations) VALUES('{"US","UK"}');
INSERT INTO countries(destinations) VALUES('{"GER","UA"}');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should unnest destinations and use the elements as keys in `json_object_agg()`. Use `'[]'::json` as an empty json array:

```
select id, json_object_agg(elem, '[]'::json)
from countries, 
lateral unnest(destinations) elem
group by id;

 id |      json_object_agg      
----+---------------------------
  1 | { "US" : [], "UK" : [] }
  2 | { "GER" : [], "UA" : [] }
(2 rows)
```